# To read last value generated by pwd using grep/sed/awk command

Tags: awk, sed, command-line, grep

To read last value generated using grep/sed/awk command

```
[root@test 4]# pwd
/opt/lib/insta/4
```

from above `pwd` to read value `4`.

i am trying something like this which is not correct exactly

```
pwd | grep -oP 'insta/?'
```

Comment: Use `echo "${PWD##*/}"`

Comment: Could you please confirm if you always want last value in path irrespective of either `insta` is present or not? Or you want to have lst value of `pwd` when insta is present as 2nd last path in it? Please confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it would be good if we are not looking for insta .. so whichever the path's, when command is executed the last value should get displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any external utility, you can do this in `bash`:

```sh
echo "${PWD##*/}"

4
```

Or using `awk`:

```sh
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' <<< "$PWD"

4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the field separator to `/` and print the last field if the second last field is insta

```
pwd | awk -F / '{
  if ($(NF-1) == "insta") {
    print $NF
  }
}'
```

Output

```
4
```

Or you could print the last field:

```
pwd | awk -F / '{print $NF}'
```